# Dockerized Rails app: slow after container start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, nginx, docker-swarm

Our Rails (5.1.7) application runs inside docker-swarm container (Ruby 2.6.5, PostgreSQL 10).

We tried Puma web-server, and it wasn't good enough under heavy load, so we use Unicorn (5.5.2).

And we are facing a big problem.

After a container start, each page loads really slow for the first time, up to one minute. All subsequent requests to the same pages respond quickly.

It looks like it is not Unicorn problem, because after `HUP` (restart) or `QUIT` (shutdown) (+ start) signals pages load fast enough.

This problem occurs after deployment (`docker stack deploy ...`), or update (`docker service update ...`).

Docker schema:

- two separate servers
- two stacks (staging + demo);
- both stacks use the same Nginx container (+ external network created to connect them)
- each stack includes:

  - PostgreSQL container
  - Rails application container
  - Redis container
  - RabbitMQ container
  - Background workers container
- Nginx service is defined only in docker-compose for demo, therefore deployment to staging does not restart Nginx container

It may be worth noting that all staging containers run on a server 1 (except Nginx), and demo containers are distributed between two servers: on server 1 we have demo PostgreSQL, Redis and RabbitMQ, and on server 2 we have Rails application, Background workers and Nginx. And the problem is reproduced on both stacks.

Any ideas how to fix the issue? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE (2020.02.24)**

There seems to be a problem in the view layer caching. I can’t show the full logs, but they are almost identical except for this line:

```
# SLOW request
I, [2020-02-24T09:47:55.634574 #464]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 57087ms (Views: 56624.1ms | ActiveRecord: 104.7ms)
```

```
# FAST request
I, [2020-02-24T09:48:21.101165 #461]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 993ms (Views: 486.6ms | ActiveRecord: 110.1ms)
```

Comment: What do your logs say? Turn the level to `debug` and provide use with log output for the first slow request and the subsequent quicker request. That could provide the clue to what is going on here.

Comment: If your app doesn't have any logs in debug mode, check the logs for the containers from the service output `docker service ps --no-trunc <service ID>`. Might your app initialize all of the connections on the first API call? You can also add `depends_on:` in your stack's `.yml` file.

Comment: @JoelMagnuson The `depends_on` option is ignored when deploying a stack in swarm mode. And `docker service ps --no-trunc <service ID>` doesn't show logs.

Comment: @PatrickQuigley question updated, please, take a look.

Answer (score 2):

After examining the logs, we've noticed, that the greatest subsidence in response time occurs on a view rendering stage:

```
# first SLOW request
I, [2020-02-24T09:47:55.634574 #464]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 57087ms (Views: 56624.1ms | ActiveRecord: 104.7ms)

# second FAST request
I, [2020-02-24T09:48:21.101165 #461]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 993ms (Views: 486.6ms | ActiveRecord: 110.1ms)
```

Therefore, we checked the default cache and realized that it simply did not persist between deployments, and on a first request application have to render view from scratch and cache it.

So, our solution was to save rails cache in a shared persistent docker volume and create a symlink to it before the application server starts. As a result, if page was cached, even the first request to open it will be super fast.

Comment: Nice follow up Taras!